# Check if an object exist in expected list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have this class POCO

```
public class BankTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public TransactionTypeEnum TransactionType { get; set; }
    public int BankAccountId { get; set; }

    public BankTransaction(decimal TransactionAmount)
    {
        this.TransactionAmount = TransactionAmount;
    }
}

public enum TransactionTypeEnum
{
    Deposit, Withdraw, ThirdPartyTransfer
}
```

and this repository class insert the transaction

```
public class BankTransactionRepository : IBankTransactionRepository
{
    // Mock DB
    public List<BankTransaction> bankTransactions { get; private set; }

    public BankTransactionRepository()
    {
        bankTransactions = new List<BankTransaction>();
    }

    public void InsertTransaction(BankTransaction bankTransaction)
    {
        bankTransactions.Add(bankTransaction);
    }
}
```

and here is my xUnit unit test for `InsertTransaction` method which works except for `expected.Should().Contain(trans);` which support to check if `trans` object exists in `expected` list.

```
public class BankTransactionsTest
{
    private BankTransactionRepository _bankTransaction;

    public BankTransactionsTest()
    {
        _bankTransaction = new BankTransactionRepository();
    }

    // Arrange
    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(InsertTransaction_InsertShouldPass_Data))]
    public void InsertTransaction_InsertShouldPass(BankTransaction trans, List<BankTransaction> expected)
    {
        // Act
        _bankTransaction.InsertTransaction(trans);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expected.Count, _bankTransaction.bankTransactions.Count);

        // Fluent Assertions to check if trans is in 'expected' list.
        expected.Should().Contain(trans);
    }

    public static TheoryData<BankTransaction, List<BankTransaction>> InsertTransaction_InsertShouldPass_Data()
    {
        return new TheoryData<BankTransaction, List<BankTransaction>>
        {
            {
                new BankTransaction(200.00M),
                new List<BankTransaction>(){new BankTransaction(200.00M)}              
            },
            {
                new BankTransaction(50.50M),
                new List<BankTransaction>(){new BankTransaction(50.50M)}
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the approach to be more explicit about asserting the expected behavior:

That the object inserted when `InsertTransaction` is invoked, is actually contained in the subject under test.

```
public class BankTransactionsTest
{
    private BankTransactionRepository _bankTransaction;

    public BankTransactionsTest()
    {
        _bankTransaction = new BankTransactionRepository();
    }

    // Arrange
    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(InsertTransaction_InsertShouldPass_Data))]
    public void InsertTransaction_InsertShouldPass(BankTransaction transaction)
    {
        // Act
        _bankTransaction.InsertTransaction(transaction);

        // Assert
        _bankTransaction.bankTransactions.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(transaction);
    }

    public static TheoryData<BankTransaction> InsertTransaction_InsertShouldPass_Data()
    {
        return new TheoryData<BankTransaction>
        {
            new BankTransaction(200.00M),
            new BankTransaction(50.50M)
        };
    }
}
```